# What can I do when Ubuntu is stuck?

Tags: process, kill, xkill

I used to work with window in the past, and when Windows was stuck (cursor doesn't move or respond to clicks, for example), I could just clicked Ctrl+Alt+Delete, open the task manager and end the task that causes the OS to stuck.

Unfortunately, this feature doesn't exist in Ubuntu. I know the command 'xkill', but it doesn't always work, and in order to use it, I first have to open a terminal. When Ubuntu is stack, sometimes it's not possible to open a terminal. I also know the commands 'lsof' and 'kill -9 ...'. Still, it's not always useful when OS is stuck.

Do you know any technique that is as effective as ctrl+alt+del in Windows?

Comment: Alt+SysRq+ S,U,B

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes) Where you can find Alt+SysRq+ S,U,B  as well as Ctrl+Alt+F1 and other ways to get Ubuntu unstuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get to console, where you can kill any process.

If that does not work either, you can reboot by Ctrl+Alt+S,U,B.